# Tensorflow: How to select rows from tensor with different size of indices?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From tensor `a` which size is `[2,3,2]`

```
a = [[[1 1]
      [2 2]
      [3 3]]

     [[4 4]
      [5 5]
      [6 6]]]
```

I want to select rows with `indices = [[0],[0,2]]`

The expected output is:

```
b = [[[1 1]]

     [[4 4]
      [6 6]]]
```

I have tried `tf.gather_nd` but it cannot select rows if the size of indices is different. 
Does that mean I cannot have a list of lists with different sizes as a tensor? If there's no way to get the expected result as a tensor `b`. Is there anyway get the result like this `c`?

```
c = [[[1 1]
      [0 0]
      [0 0]]

     [[4 4]
      [0 0]
      [6 6]]]
```

Comment: Could you generate `b` based off `a` without `tensor` and then use the result with `tensor`?

Comment: @PacketLoss I think I can't do that in my original code because `a` is generated as `tensor` from the start in the main computational graph. So I would like to do it in `tensor` form.